# android button and listener. how can i get it more short

Tags: android, kotlin

I am making some buttons and listener for it. but i think it is too long and complicated.
So can i get it more briefly?

here is my code

```
fun init_cardView() {
    activity_cardview.setOnClickListener(myOnClickListener)
    alertdialog_cardview.setOnClickListener(myOnClickListener)
    animation_cardview.setOnClickListener(myOnClickListener)
    widgets_cardview.setOnClickListener(myOnClickListener)
    container_cardview.setOnClickListener(myOnClickListener)
    date_cardview.setOnClickListener(myOnClickListener)
    explicitintent_cardview.setOnClickListener(myOnClickListener)
    implicitintent_cardview.setOnClickListener(myOnClickListener)
    fragment_cardview.setOnClickListener(myOnClickListener)
    wifimanager_cardview.setOnClickListener(myOnClickListener)
    menu_cardview.setOnClickListener(myOnClickListener)
    image_cardview.setOnClickListener(myOnClickListener)
    time_cardview.setOnClickListener(myOnClickListener)
    toast_cardview.setOnClickListener(myOnClickListener)
}

fun init_MyOnClickListener() {
    myOnClickListener = View.OnClickListener {
        var intent: Intent? = null
        when (it.id) {
            R.id.activity_cardview -> intent = Intent(applicationContext, Activity::class.java)
            R.id.alertdialog_cardview -> intent =
                Intent(applicationContext, AlertDialog::class.java)
            R.id.animation_cardview -> intent =
                Intent(applicationContext, Animation::class.java)
            R.id.widgets_cardview -> intent = Intent(applicationContext, Widgets::class.java)
            R.id.container_cardview -> intent =
                Intent(applicationContext, Container::class.java)
            R.id.date_cardview -> intent = Intent(applicationContext, Date::class.java)
            R.id.explicitintent_cardview -> intent =
                Intent(applicationContext, ExplicitIntent::class.java)
            R.id.implicitintent_cardview -> intent =
                Intent(applicationContext, ImplicitIntent::class.java)
            R.id.fragment_cardview -> intent = Intent(applicationContext, Fragment::class.java)
            R.id.wifimanager_cardview -> intent =
                Intent(applicationContext, WifiManager::class.java)
            R.id.menu_cardview -> intent = Intent(applicationContext, Menu::class.java)
            R.id.image_cardview -> intent = Intent(applicationContext, Image::class.java)
            R.id.time_cardview -> intent = Intent(applicationContext, Time::class.java)
            R.id.toast_cardview -> intent = Intent(applicationContext, Toast::class.java)
            else -> {
                intent = null
            }
        }
        if (intent != null) {
            Log.d("myOnclickListener", "${it.id}");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
                .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove `init_MyOnClickListener` and just initialize it at the definition (wherever that may be).  Other than that, I don't think you could make it any shorter without sacrificing readability.

Comment: Thank you for reply. you mean i should define each listener to each setOnClickListener function?

Comment: You're setting a `myOnClickListener` variable there.  You could just define it as `val myOnClickListener = View.OnClickListener { ... }` at the point where it's defined.

Comment: Oh i got it. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 3):

So simple. Just define a method for example `onCustomClick` in your activity which **gets a view as parameter** and write whatever you want to do in it. then define the `android:onClick="onCustomClick"`  attribute in your xml file for any button you want them to use `onCustomClick` method
**add this to your activity**

```
fun onCustomClick(v: View) {
        when (v.id) {
            R.id.button1 -> Log.i("TAG", "button 1 clicked")
            R.id.button2 -> Log.i("TAG", "button 2 clicked")
            R.id.button3 -> Log.i("TAG", "button 3 clicked")
        }
    }
```

**and add this attribute to your buttons in xml file**

```
android:onClick="onCustomClick"
```